# Firebase Phone Auth adding SHA1 not creates corresponding auth client id

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Phone Auth in react native application. I followed the documentation with the setup, but I'm getting this error on Android:

> This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication.Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console

I checked SHA1 and package name. To my understanding when I add new SHA1 hash corresponding OAuth2 Client Id is autogenerated in Google Cloud, but it seems like it didn't trigger (I've added 6 SHA1 keys, but have only 4 OAuth2 Client Ids). I assume that this might be a problem, but I have no clue how to resolve that. Any ideas?

I'm thinking about manually creating OAuth2 Client Id, but I wouldn't like to mess with firebase autogenerated stuff.